# Is a function with a closed graph continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and denote $A_f=\{(x,f(x)),x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

I've proved that if $f$ is continuous, then $A_f$ is closed. But I have no clue for the other direction. Does $A_f$ closed also imply $f$ continuous?

Thanks a lot~

Comment: So $A_f$ is the graph of $f(x)$?

Comment: @marshalcraft It's just a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @marshalcraft Yes, it looks so.

Comment: Also do you mean $A_f$ is closed as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$? Sorry.

Comment: Also isn't any curve closed? As the complement for any point you can find an open ball contained in the complement, thus open.

Comment: @marshalcraft no, $(-1,1)\times\{0\}$ is an not closed curve. A curve needs to contain it's endpoints (or have endpoints at complex $\infty$ to be closed.

Comment: @Stella Biderman Ok, is that a curve though, seems like just two points.

Comment: @marshalcraft It's supposed to represent the open interval $(-1,1)$ embedded into $\mathbb{R}^2$ and viewed as a subset of the $x$-axis. The point $(-1,1,0)$ isn't in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and would be denoted $\{(-1,1)\}\times\{0\}$

Comment: Ok yes I see it is the n tuple from $(-1,1)$ and zero for y. Exactly as you said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x} & \text{ if }x\ne 0,\\
0 & \text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}
$$
The graph $A_f$ consists of three disconnected closed parts, thus, closed, but the function is not continuous. I think you need $f$ to be locally bounded.

Comment: +1: Good answer. I had confused "graph" and "image" lolz.

Comment: This should be marked as answer.

Comment: @marshalcraft yep, So. Great answer